# how to change openlayers marker icon?

Tags: dictionary, openlayers

I am using Openlayers to my application.

i have succeeded in showing marker when i click on the map, but now i want to change the marker icon when i click on that, how to do this. I didn't find any method like `marker.setIcon();`

i am really confusing here.

```
map.events.register("click", map , function(e){
   var opx = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy) ;
   var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(opx);
   markers.addMarker(marker);
   marker.events.register("click", marker, function(e){
    //here i want to change the icon to some other 
    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
                         marker.lonlat,
                         new OpenLayers.Size(200, 200),
                         "example popup",
                         null, true);

     map.addPopup(popup);
       }); 
    // here i want to change to default.
  });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation at **OpenLayers 2**:

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html

mentions the method setUrl to set the icon image. This should work:

```
marker.setUrl('marker.png');
```

Comment: hey, in open layers 4 i get an error saying this is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

I got answer from [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/1031), here is the code

```
marker.events.register('click', marker, function() {
  // Reset all markers.
  for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].icon.imageDiv.firstChild.setAttribute(
      'src', 'images/red.png');
  }
  this.icon.imageDiv.firstChild.setAttribute('src', 'images/blue.png');
});
```

Comment: This bypasses the OpenLayers API so it's a little hackish.